# RPC and IPC data marshalling

Tags: networking, marshalling, unmarshalling

In RPC, the stubs at client and server needs to marshal and unmarshal data, then it sends it to the Lower layer to send it over network. Do TCP/IP also Marshal the data to binary stream? Why the Middleware needs to marshal the invocation request?

I'm trying to understand am so confused because as I know using IPC we don't marshal the data we just use send() and recv().

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The job of the proxy is to marshal the call from the client by serializing the arguments to bytes so it can be transmitted across the network.  The stub in the server deserializes them again and makes the call.  Possible return values go back the same way.

There is no marshaling in TCP, it just transmit bytes.